High ESD voltage but low input voltage?
I am watching this video, and the datasheet for the 74ls245, and what I saw was that the ESD voltage is >3500 Volts, but the input voltage Ben Eater uses is 5 volts. My question is why is the ESD voltage higher than the input voltages. Also wouldn't sending 3500 volts to the IC, destroy it in the sense that it completely burns?

ESD is not rated as a fixed voltage, but is a type rating. Included in the standard[1], is the peak or initial voltage, the waveform (within some tolerance) into a standard (resistive termination) load, the impedance, energy, and many details of how to construct and test it (equivalent circuit and geometry).  Since the risetime is very fast, construction details are important: an ESD pulse very much travels at the speed of light, a small but no less significant EMP blast.
As a result, it might be 3500V open-circuit, but due to the impedance (say 330Ω typical), the peak current into a short circuit (~0V) might be 10A.
For most devices, a low-impedance (surge shunting) protection strategy is used, keeping the voltage across the device low, dropping the remainder of the pulse voltage across the external circuit (the pulse generator internally, and connections; indeed, significant energy is dissipated as radiation into space).
The impedance might not be perfectly low.  For example the peak voltage at the pin of an IC, during an ESD strike, might be 10s to 100s of V.  A good TVS can clamp this as low as 20V or so; much lower is difficult to achieve, without adding more branches to the circuit, for example adding a series resistor into a second shunt device (TVS, clamp diodes, etc.).
3500V is not a bad rating, and is generally adequate for handling without special precautions (but not zero, you can easily build up more than that in a dry environment, and need to discharge that safely otherwise).  This is one of the historical features of TTL, that it was a bit more robust than CMOS devices were at the time (back when PMOS, NMOS and CMOS were new competitors -- 60s to 80s say).
As for actual damage, it may cause partial failure (damaged but not completely destroyed microscopic structures inside the IC), which causes immediate malfunction, or doesn't -- or does, but only after some time of otherwise normal operation.  It may even "fix itself" subsequently.  Partially damaged circuits can be very spooky, as function comes and goes, or excess supply current is drawn (including acute effects like CMOS latchup), etc.
The manufacturer's quality policy can be consulted (or ask an FAE) for what level of ESD they test at (if not listed in the datasheet), and what failure criterion (statistical sampling) they use.
[1] IEC 61000-4-2 is the most prominent example.

The ESD rating is for brief incidental pulses from static electricity. They are shunted away from the sensitive parts of the chip by a network of diodes to the supply rails. A common configuration is to have diodes to each supply like so:

This is the input circuit of an ATmega328P
But these diodes are not meant to pass large, continuous currents so the limit on the pins is usually given as Vdd + 0.3 volts (and Vss - 0.3V) or so since this is the forward voltage of the protection diode.
The 74LS245 has a slightly different input protection configuration:

There is a Zener diode from the input to ground. The Zener voltage appears to be 7V since that is the absolute maximum input voltage according to the datasheet. Minimum input voltage is -1.5V referenced to ground since the diode would start conduct in the forward direction.

Anticipating the OP's understanding of physical chip design: "ESD" means Electrostatic Discharge. On a macro level, ESD is lightning (literally). On a micro level, ESD can be the spark from your fingertip when you touch a door knob. The indicated chip is NOT designed to accept 3500 volts on its power/input pins. It's designed to handle a very brief spike (ESD, think "lightning strike" only faster) up to 3500 volts on its input pins to protect the chip from problems arising from mishandling during packaging, shipping, installation, etc.
